# Countdown Timer that is date and time specific

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown

```
    txtTimerDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerDay);
    txtTimerHour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerHour);
    txtTimerMinute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerMinute);
    txtTimerSecond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerSecond);
    tvEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhappyevent);

    countDownStart();
}

public void countDownStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd");
                // Please here set your event date//YYYY-MM-DD
                Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2017-03-18");
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)) {
                    long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                            - currentDate.getTime();
                    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                    diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                    long seconds = diff / 1000;
```

Okay... Here is my question... Currently in this code... The Output which includes the layout and some more lines...
Will generate a proper timer heading towards march 18th... However... I need the timer to countdown towards march 18th at 20.30 at night.. Any Help will be appreciated and please tolerate me.. i am new in this website

Comment: Please generate the minimal code. For example all the lines that define the various views are not relevant for the problem. Then explain how you expect the code to work and put some indication (such as println) where and what you expect the output to be. Finally I think the answer may be to use DateTime instead of Date class.

Comment: try out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045576/create-service-with-countdowntimer-in-android/41045622#41045622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class cal {
public static int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.setTime(new Date(0)); /* reset */
    thatDay.set(Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);/*here Add ur Time */
    thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
    thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,0); // 0-11 so 1 less
    thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    long diff =  thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis(); 
    long diffSec = diff / 1000;

    long days = diffSec / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
    long secondsDay = diffSec % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
    long seconds = secondsDay % 60;
    long minutes = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
    long hours = (secondsDay / 3600); // % 24 not needed

    System.out.printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds\n", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
}
```

Try To use Calender It will help to set your Time and Date Try it....do not forget to accept if goal is accomplished